# An active access token must be used to query information about the current user error when posting video to facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

This is my code to post a video to facebook:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];

NSArray * p = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"basic_info", nil];

NSDictionary * dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"xxx",ACFacebookAppIdKey,p,ACFacebookPermissionsKey,ACFacebookAudienceEveryone,ACFacebookAudienceKey, nil];

NSDictionary *options = @{
                          ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"xxx",
                          ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream, " ],
                          ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends,
                          };
ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore
                                      accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:dict completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"blablalba");
    //do nothing here.
    if (granted) {
        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if (granted) {
                NSLog(@"posting to fb..");


                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"];

                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                NSURL *videoPathURL = [defaults URLForKey:@"vidURL"];

                //        NSURL *videoPathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:videoPath isDirectory:NO];
                //        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoPath];
                NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[videoPathURL path]];

                NSString *status = @"One step closer.";
                NSDictionary *params = @{@"title":status, @"description":status};

                SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                  URL:url
                                                           parameters:params];

                [request addMultipartData:videoData
                                 withName:@"source"
                                     type:@"video/quicktime"
                                 filename:[videoPathURL absoluteString]];

                [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                    }
                    NSLog(@"httpresponse: %@", urlResponse);
                }];
            }
        }];
    }

}];
```

But its returning:

> "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.\"";

I have no idea what I'm missing. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to set the facebook account to the request.
When you are granted the access, fetch the account:

```
                           NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore
                                accountsWithAccountType:fbAccountType];
                        self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
```

and after creating the request, set the account

```
    [request setAccount:self.facebookAccount];
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that I had to add the token to the params field:

```
NSString *status = @"One step closer.";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"title":status, @"description":status, @"access_token":accessToken};
```

Hope it helps others.